# combining all search patterns -TCL regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

How to combine all the patterns in one regexp command? Is there a way for it?

Example: If my variable is "a" and if I need to check "a" for more than 1 pattern, how to do this in a single command? 
I tried something like

```
    set a abc
    regexp ".abc | abc. | .abc." $a
```

This returned 1 as output. But it should be zero as all my patterns has a "." and not matching with $a

Comment: Please modify the question so that you use different variables for the string to be searched and the pattern you are searching for. Now I'm little confused what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I updated. Thanks !

Comment: I found that it works when I use parenthesis between each search pattern

Comment: Consider reading something like ["Mastering regular expressions"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) as your question is really too basic (and has nothing to do with Tcl).

Comment: FWIW, the code _exactly_ as written produces `0` as its result; those spaces are significant by default…

Comment: … and `.` is a “match any character” of course.

Answer (score 2):

You're failing because a space character represents a space character in regexp. So your regexp:

```
regexp ".abc | abc. | .abc." $a
```

is looking for:

```
"anything" followed by "a" then "b" then "c" then " "
OR
" " followed by "a" then "b" then "c" then "anything" then " "
OR
" " followed by "anything" then "a" then "b" then "c" then "anything"
```

Obviously the string "abc" matches none of the patterns above for the following reasons:

1. It doesn't contain any space character (in the right places) which is required by all 3 conditions.
2. There's no character before "a" to match pattern 1 & 2 and there's not character after "c" to match pattern 2 & 3

What you probably want is something like this:

```
regexp ".abc|abc.|.abc." $a
```

but the above still doesn't match "abc". It would match "abcd" because there's an extra character after "c". To match "abc" as well you'd need:

```
regexp ".abc|abc.|.abc.|abc" $a
```

But I suspect that this is a minor issue. The core of your problem is you don't realize that regular expressions also interpret whitespace as something to search for.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I use parenthesis  for each search pattern

```
    regexp "(.abc)|(abc.)|(.abc.)" $a
```

Comment: You can also lose the quotation marks completely `regexp .abc|abc.|.abc. $a` or better yet, use curly braces `regexp {.abc|abc.|.abc.} $a`. With curly braces no substitutions are done inside the search pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend OpenBSD's [re_format(7)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=re_format&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html) man page for a very compact and correct POSIX regular expressions reference.